# Strange behavior of increment operator in c language

Tags: c++, c

Look at this code the code below it has a strange behavior the output should be 18 but when i try to compile and run it in **Turbo C** or in **Code::Block** the output is 19 instead of 18.

```
int main() {
    int n=4, x;
    x = ++n + ++n + ++n;
    printf("%d", x);
    return 0;
 }
```

Can some explain it to me How the output is 19 instead of 18.

**Note: when i try to run same code in java the output is 18 as expected.**

But in c/c++ the output is 19 please explain

**Thanks in Advance.**